# ojAlgo Change seed of random number generator

Tags: ojalgo

Can I somehow change the seed of the rngs of Uniform/Normal? Gonna be tough to make simulations that can be reproduced if you can not set the seed.

Answer (score 1):

That's currently not possible, but if you create an issue for it at https://github.com/optimatika/ojAlgo/issues it can be fixed.

Comment: It is now possible.